# How to calculate how many digits in a number from index notation

Tags: decimal-expansion

How can you calculate how many digits are in a number from its index notation?

I need to calculate how many digits are in the number $2^{30} * 5^{25}$

Answer (score 2):

$2^{30}\times5^{25} = 10^{25}\times2^{5} = 32 \times 10^{25}$

**Edit**

So, there are two digits for 32 and 25 zeros after it. 27 in total.

Comment: Is that how many digits are in the number though?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, see the edit

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks! I'll accept this when possible

Answer (score 1):

For your particular case, $2^{30} \cdot 5^{25} = 2^5\cdot 10^{25}$, which should be straightforward, given that $10^n$ is the smallest number with $n{+}1$ digits.

Comment: Is that how many digits are in the number though?

Comment: Replace $25$  (in $2^5\cdot 10^{25}$) with small numbers like $1,2,3$ to see the pattern.

Comment: I understand now, thanks!